# How to copy file from network to local drive vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a file in `\\CompName\sqlexpress\foldername\...` and i want to copy it to the local drive `C:\users\CompName>\...` i tried using `file.copy(uncpath, path, true)`  It throws a `DirectoryNotFoundException` for the unc path.  Do I have to convert unc path to a normal path? what is the right approach here?
Thank you.

Comment: Check folder permissions on the network drive.  File.Copy works...If it's not seeing the directory, it's either a permissions issue, or there is a typo in the path.  If not permissions, use Path.Combine for clarity, it will help you figure out where the issue is.

Comment: Thank you. I found the mistake on the way i enabled filestream for my database. Now, the directory exists.

Answer (score 0):

This link might help. It copies an existing file to a new file although I'm sure you'll be able to tweak it to do what you would like it to do.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6cfw35a(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1